# What is a starfinite set?

Tags: logic, model-theory, nonstandard-analysis, nonstandard-models

In the book *Field Arithmetic* by Fried and Jarden, the following definition is given on p. 273:

> Consider an enlargement of a higher order structure that contains both $P$ and $K$. Call the elements of $\mathcal{P}^*_{\mathrm{fin}}(P)$ the **starfinite subsets** of $P^*$.

What is a starfinite set? I can't understand the definition.

Comment: You say you cannot understand the definition. What *is* the definition?

Comment: In the book FIELD ARITHMETIC the only thing that I could take as a definition was: Call the elements of $P*_fin (p)$ the STARFINITE subsets of $p*$.

Comment: Ok, at  the very least, you should quote the definition and cite the source in the question. I've edited to show you a proper way to ask your question. But there's still more context  you could give: The quoted definition is as explicit as it gets.  What  is it you have trouble understanding? Is it the notation $\mathcal{P}^*_{\text{fin}}$?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought starfinite subsets are the same as finite internal subsets....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A set $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is finite iff it is contained in $\{0, \ldots, n\}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Applying transfer, an *internal* set $A \subseteq {}^*\mathbb{N}$ is $*$-finite iff it is contained in $\{0, \ldots, \xi\}$ for some $\xi \in {}^* \mathbb{N}$.

---

Edit: equivalently, a $*$-finite set is an element of ${}^* \mathcal{P}_\mathrm{fin}(\mathbb{N})$, where $\mathcal{P}_\mathrm{fin}(\mathbb{N})$ is the collection of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: So classically, finite subsets of ${}^* \mathbb{N}$ are exactly the bounded ones. $*$-finite is the correct generalisation in the nonstandard universe (i.e. $*$-finite sets are the ones bounded by a nonstandard integer).

Comment: I'm not familiar with how this terminology is used in nonstandard analysis, but I would have expected a star-finite set to be an *internal* bounded set. E.g. the set of standard natural numbers is bounded by a non-standard natual number, but I would expect it to not be star-finite.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: yes, you're right. I've edited the post.